# Delegate respondsToSelector not being called for Protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, protocols

I am new to Delegate methods. I am wondering why my "respondsToSelector" is not being called for my delegate. I am sure I got everything in the right place. If you need any more information, please let me know!!! Ive looked around but I still havent found a solution that works!

Thanks all!

MODAL.h

```
    @protocol Profession <NSObject>

    -(void)profession:(NSString *)job;

    @end


   @interface ProfessionListingViewController : UIViewController        <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>{

NSString *string;
}
   @property (nonatomic, weak) id<Profession> myDelegate;
   @end
```

MODAL.m

```
    @synthesize myDelegate;
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      self.profession = @"Testing!!";

      if([self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(profession:)]){
      [self.myDelegate profession:self.profession];
      }
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

VIEW.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "ProfessionListingViewController.h"
    #import "LocationViewController.h"
    @interface ProfessionViewController : UIViewController <Profession>
```

VIEW.m

```
    -(IBAction)toProfessionListView:(id)sender{
      ProfessionListingViewController *modal = [[ProfessionListingViewController    alloc] init];
      modal.myDelegate = self;
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ModalProfessionList" sender:sender];
     }

     -(void)profession:(NSString *)job{
        NSString *test = job;
        NSLog(@"%@", test);
    }
```

Comment: I assume you mean that your delegate does not respond to the selector? Or was the problem that the line with `respondsToSelector` was not reached?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint on the `if([self.myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(profession:)]){` line. Check that self.myDelegate is indeed an instance of your Profession implementation.

Comment: @Krumelur Yeah it does not respond to the selector. It does not go into the if statement and goes right now to dismissView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you're actually doing this backwards - I'd put declare the delegate view, and the modal should become the view's delegate.

That said, if you want to do it this way, I suspect the problem is that you're performing a segue to a new instance of the modal view controller:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ModalProfessionList" sender:sender];
```

What you probably want to do instead is use `prepareForSegue:`, grab the instance of your modal view, and set the delegate there:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ModalProfessionList"])
    {
        ProfessionListingViewController *modal = [segue destinationViewController];
        modal.myDelegate = self;
    }
}
```